# Simple SQL Query framing

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm relatively new to SQL and postgres. I've relation R1 and R2 with few columns , one each being some measurement,say R1.m and R2.m . Now i need to find for every row in R1 , the minimum of some function f of (R1.m and R2.m) , `f(R1.m,R2.m)` so that the code is something like `select R1.name, R2.name from R1,R2 where f(R1.m,R2.m) < .......` . I'm not able to fill up this query . I need a row of R2 for every row in R1 which minimizes the function. I know this is simple , just cant work it out for a newbie . (In postgres)

Comment: You may want to explain a bit about this function f you are trying to do. It isn't very clear what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it

```
select distinct on (r1.name)
    r1.name, r2.name, f(r1.m, r2.m)
from r1 cross join r2
order by r1.name, f(r1.m, r2.m)
```

`distinct on` will return one only `r1.name`, the first one computed from the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I undrestand your question correctly, try something like this:

```
with 

r1 as (select generate_series(1,10,1) as m)
,r2 as (select generate_series(10,20,1) as m)

,cte as (
   select
      r1.m as "r1.m",
      r2.m as "r2.m",
      sin(r1.m * r2.m) f_r1r2,
      dense_rank() over (partition by r1.m order by sin(r1.m * r2.m)) as f_r1r2_rank
   from
      r1,
      r2
   )

select
   *
from
   cte
where
   f_r1r2_rank = 1
```

This will:

1. Create cross product or `r1` and `r2` (get all possible combinations of `r1.m` and `r2.m`)
2. Calculate function `f` (in my case I used `sin(r1.m*r2.m)` as an example)
3. Calculate rank for every set of combination of `r1` and `r2`
4. Select only those where rank = 1 (minimum)

In other words this will answer question: "What `r2.m` should I use to get minimum of function `f(r1.m,r2.m)` given `r1.m`?".

Because you have not provided sample data, I've generated my own. To make it work, you have to use something like:

```
with     
cte as (
   select
      r1.m as "r1.m",
      r2.m as "r2.m",
      sin(r1.m * r2.m) f_r1r2,
      dense_rank() over (partition by r1.m order by sin(r1.m * r2.m)) as f_r1r2_rank
   from
      r1,
      r2
   )

select
   *
from
   cte
where
   f_r1r2_rank = 1
```

and of course, you have to replace `sin(r1.m * r2.m)` with your own function.